# Nodejs websocket close event didn't work

Tags: node.js

I have a Nodejs simple server  using ws module.
When client connected to server and then I  disconneted  internet from PC but in server close event not emitted.

Example is bellow:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
, wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
});
ws.send('something');

ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('closed.');
});
});
```

Comment: I guess you need to wait for the connection to "expire" server-side. The server doesn't know immediately that you disconnected. There must be a timeout of several seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add event "error" :

```
ws.on("error", function(error) {
    // Manage error here
    console.log(error);
});
```

If this doesn't work, use Socket.io (npm install socket.io)